# Command Line Edit .CSV File

Tags: linux, bash, csv, sed, scripting

I have a .CSV file where rows have the same ID.

Here's an example .CSV file:

```
Alias,Date,Volume,Type,Type2,MSI
ID1,20170418,0.516006112,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-1
ID2,20170418,4.03900528,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-2
ID2,20170418,0.399999887,METER,OIL,10-10-10-2
ID2,20170418,0,METER,CONDY,10-10-10-2
ID3,20170418,0.399999887,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-3
ID4,20170418,6.599591255,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-4
ID5,20170418,4.6501894,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-5
ID6,20170418,1.831178546,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-6
ID6,20170418,0.190000013,METER,OIL,10-10-10-6
ID6,20170418,0,METER,CONDY,10-10-10-6
```

I need to create a Linux script to edit this .CSV file, to look like this:

```
Alias,Date,Volume,Type,Type2,MSI,Volume Oil, Volume Condy
ID1,20170418,0.516006112,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-1,,
ID2,20170418,4.03900528,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-2,0.399999887,0
ID3,20170418,0.399999887,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-3,,
ID4,20170418,6.599591255,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-4,,
ID5,20170418,4.6501894,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-5,,
ID6,20170418,1.831178546,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-6,0.190000013,0
```

If the Alias field is repeated...

And row has METER OIL: Move volume to 'Volume Oil' in previous row, delete this row

And row has METER CONDY: move volume to 'Volume Condy' in previous row, delete this row

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: With SED I was able to add the title (first row)

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach(supposing there could be only three records with same `ID`):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "Alias,Date,Volume,Type,Type2,MSI,Volume Oil,Volume Condy"; }
         NR>1{ (a[$1])? gsub(/,*$/, FS$3, a[$1]) : a[$1]=$0 FS FS}
         END{ for(i in a) print a[i] }' file.csv
```

The output:

```
Alias,Date,Volume,Type,Type2,MSI,Volume Oil,Volume Condy
ID1,20170418,0.516006112,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-1,,
ID2,20170418,4.03900528,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-2,0.399999887,0
ID3,20170418,0.399999887,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-3,,
ID4,20170418,6.599591255,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-4,,
ID5,20170418,4.6501894,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-5,,
ID6,20170418,1.831178546,CHART,GAS,10-10-10-6,0.190000013,0
```

Comment: This looks good, except it left the metre condy value of 0 out.

Comment: @TrevorWelsh, apologize, fixed. now it's fine

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I just have to figure out how all that works :)